# Code doesn't execute until button triggered

Tags: php, mysql

I need your help. So the problem is that I've done some coding but I don't know why it doesn't work when page loads. But when I trigger any button (Save Info Modification Or Cancel Info Modification) it works.

php code :

```
if(isset($_POST['nametb']) && isset($_POST['usernametb']) && isset($_POST['emailtb']) && isset($_POST['confirmtb']) && isset($_POST['abouttb']) && isset($_POST['interesttb']) && isset($_POST['dreamtb']) && isset($_POST['liketb']) && isset($_POST['schooltb']) && isset($_POST['schoolyrtb']) && isset($_POST['occupationtb']) && isset($_POST['occupationyrtb'])){

            $select_info = "SELECT * from user_info WHERE id='$user_id'";

            if($select_info_run = @mysql_query($select_info)){

                $namedb = mysql_result($select_info_run, 0, 'name');
                $usernamedb = mysql_result($select_info_run, 0, 'username');
                $emaildb = mysql_result($select_info_run, 0, 'email');
                $confirmdb = mysql_result($select_info_run, 0, 'email');
                $aboutdb = mysql_result($select_info_run, 0, 'about');
                $interestdb = mysql_result($select_info_run, 0, 'interest');
                $dreamdb = mysql_result($select_info_run, 0, 'dream');
                $likedb = mysql_result($select_info_run, 0, 'like');
                $schooldb = mysql_result($select_info_run, 0, 'school');
                $schoolyrdb = mysql_result($select_info_run, 0, 'schoolyr');
                $occupationdb = mysql_result($select_info_run, 0, 'occupation');
                $occupationyrdb = mysql_result($select_info_run, 0, 'occupationyr');

            }
            else{
                echo 'Server down :(';
            }


        }
            else{
                echo server down :(';
            }
```

html code :

```
<form action="<?php if(isset($current_file)){ echo $current_file; } ?>" method="POST">  
<fieldset id="fieldset1">
<legend style="font-family: Ubuntu; font-size:20px;">Info</legend>
<label id="name" title="Name" for="textbox1">Name :</label>
<label id="username" title="UserName" for="textbox2">UserName :</label>
<label id="email" title="Email" for="textbox3">Email :</label>
<label id="confirm" title="Confirm Email" for="textbox4">Confirm :</label>
<br />
<input type="text" id="textbox1" name="nametb" value="<?php if(isset($namedb)){ echo $namedb; } ?>" />
<input type="text" id="textbox2" name="usernametb" value="<?php if(isset($usernamedb)){ echo $usernamedb; } ?>" />
<input type="text" id="textbox3" name="emailtb" value="<?php if(isset($emaildb)){ echo $emaildb; } ?>" />
<input type="text" id="textbox4" name="confirmtb" value="<?php if(isset($confirmdb)){ echo $confirmdb; } ?>" />
<br /><br />
<div id="hrln"><hr /></div>                                                                          
<label id="about" title="About you" for="textarea1">About :</label>
<label id="interest" title="You are interested in?" for="textarea2">Interested in :</label>
<br />  
<textarea id="textarea1" name="abouttb"><?php if(isset($aboutdb)){ echo $aboutdb; } ?></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea2" name="interesttb"><?php if(isset($interestdb)){ echo $interestdb; } ?></textarea>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><hr />
<label id="dream" title="Your Dream?" for="textarea3">Dream :</label>
<label id="like" title="What do you like?" for="textarea4">You like :</label>
<br />  
<textarea id="textarea3" name="dreamtb"><?php if(isset($dreamdb)){ echo $dreamdb; } ?></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea4" name="liketb"><?php if(isset($likedb)){ echo $likedb; } ?></textarea>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><hr />
<label id="education" title="Your school" for="textbox5">School | University :</label>
<label id="educationyr" title="Year" for="textbox6">Year :</label>
<br />
<input type="text" name="schooltb" id="textbox5" value="<?php if(isset($schooldb)){ echo $schooldb; } ?>" />
<input type="text" name="schoolyrtb" id="textbox6" value="<?php if(isset($schoolyrdb)){ echo $schoolyrdb; } ?>" />
<br /><br /><hr />
<label id="occupation" title="Occupation" for="textbox7">Occupation :</label>
<label id="occupationyr" title="Year" for="textbox6">Year :</label>
<br />
<input type="text" id="textbox7" name="occupationtb" value="<?php if(isset($occupationdb)){ echo $occupationdb; } ?>" />
<input type="text" id="textbox8" name="occupationyrtb" value="<?php if(isset($occupationyrdb)){ echo $occupationyrdb; } ?>" />
<br /><br /><hr />
<label id="passwords" title="For Security Purpose" for="textbox9">Password :</label>
<input type="password" id="textbox9" name="passwordstb" />
<input type="submit" value="Save Info Modification" name="save" id="button1" />
<input type="submit" value="Cancel Info Modification" name="cancel" id="button2" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Because everything in your code is inside the `if ($_POST...)` condition. Of course it does't run until you POST something. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Your 2nd "else{
            echo server down :(';
        }" is missing a quote before 'server down :(';

Comment: sorry i mistyped that, even though it isn't working..

Comment: What is it you want to do? Do you want the form to display? Then, get rid of that echo in the last "else". Then the form will display. When a user clicks the submit button, the form will post that information to the page.

Comment: sir it worked, by removing isset, sir one more suggestion, can u tell what does isset do, because i tried to find out but every defination was going out of my mind, could you please tell me...

Comment: It will check if the value exists, is not NULL, and exists in the header or body part of the page when it is loaded. When you load a php page, it can check in the "loading" of it if there are values also sent in the page request. Google it. http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: then it means both isset and empty are same?is that so...

Comment: @KrishnaSarswat: There is an example of the difference between isset and empty here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the form to display? Then, get rid of that echo in the last "else". Then the form will display. When a user clicks the submit button, the form will post that information to the page.

Also, your 2nd "else{ echo server down :('; }" is missing a quote before 'server down :(';

The key to your problems is what I call "isolation": you need to isolate what is causing the issue. I recommend the "comment-out-code-and-refresh-page" technique if you're pressed for time. But it's far better to analyze and interpret your code and UNDERSTAND why it's not doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It runs when you click the buttons because of this:

```
if(isset($_POST['nametb']) && isset($_POST['usernametb']) && isset($_POST['emailtb']) &&
 isset($_POST['confirmtb']) && isset($_POST['abouttb']) && isset($_POST['interesttb']) &&
 isset($_POST['dreamtb']) && isset($_POST['liketb']) && isset($_POST['schooltb']) &&
 isset($_POST['schoolyrtb']) && isset($_POST['occupationtb']) &&
 isset($_POST['occupationyrtb'])){
```

Your if statement is checking if anything in the POST array is set before doing anything.
This is sent by the form when you click a submit button (which is either button, it seems).

If you are trying to populate the fields on page load, you need to move your SELECT statement an related code outside of that if statement. Since it seems you would be using this form to update database data, you should put your INSERT/UPDATE statements inside the if statement so that they won't run until you click the submit button (pending other logical operations to take into account WHICH button was pressed.).

Comment: thank you very much both of you, now this time it just fixed in my mind...thank you once again....